# calling racket from Java

Tags: java, python, racket

I saw [this link](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/embedding.html) for calling racket from C/C++ (assuming it's still up to date). Is there a similar way to call racket programs from Java or python?

Answer (score 0):

You can call Racket programs from Java using Process API. some examples [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/)

This way You will cal a Racket command with parameters and read from it's out stream. Similarly to Unix streams...
I do not believe that it is possible to compile everything into one binary like in the link you gave, but it may be good enough workaround/glue code for  time.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can do something like this:

```
from os import system as call
cmd = '/home/n/racket/bin/racket'
call(cmd)
```

Another way (recommended these days):

```
from subprocess import call
call('/home/n/racket/bin/racket', 'tmp.rkt')
```